# using image_data for opensea's metadata instead of image

Tags: nft, erc-721, opensea, meta-data

I understand it is not recommended, but I was curious about including the code for an SVG in `image_data` which would replace `image` per opensea's [metadata standards page](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards). This:

```json
{
  "description": "Friendly OpenSea Creature that enjoys long swims in the ocean.", 
  "external_url": "https://openseacreatures.io/3", 
  "image": "https://storage.googleapis.com/opensea-prod.appspot.com/puffs/3.png", 
  "name": "Dave Starbelly",
  "attributes": [ ... ]
}
```

is their example of OpenSea-compliant metadata. So would I be able to do something like:

```json
{
  "description": ..., 
  "external_url": ..., 
  "image_data": "
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
      <rect width='300' height='300'/>
    </svg>
  ", 
  "name": ...,
  "attributes": [ ... ]
}
```

Or would I have to encode or something else? thanks.

Comment: Did you find the answer after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct; you don't need to encode more of the SVG, just the raw data.

My only additional suggestion is to put everything on the same line, in case you edited the SVG manually, avoiding different ways to create new lines in a text file (carriage returns, new line feeds, etc.).

```json
{
  "description": ..., 
  "external_url": ..., 
  "image_data": "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <rect width='300' height='300'/> </svg>", 
  "name": ...,
  "attributes": [...]
}
```

You can watch an interesting video explaining ["How to store NFT metadata and SVG image completely on-chain (ERC721/ERC1155)"](https://youtu.be/QVWs9e4RFSA). It's an end-to-end tutorial, from the smart contract to viewing the NFT on testnet through OpenSea.

As a reference, here the differences between the `image` and the `image_data` attributes:

> `image`: *This is the URL to the image of the item. Can be just about any
> type of image (including SVGs, which will be cached into PNGs by
> OpenSea), and can be IPFS URLs or paths. We recommend using a 350 x
> 350 image.*
>
> `image_data`: *Raw SVG image data, if you want to generate
> images on the fly (not recommended). Only use this if you're not
> including the image parameter.*

Comment: I will happily mark this answer as accepted if you could explain what is the difference between `image` and `image_data`?

Comment: Sure, I added some notes, even though it seems to me the question is about the correct format to use for the value of the `image_data` attribute, more than the differences between `image` and `image_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an example](https://opensea.io/assets/optimism/0x49966af5103150146f58be7c41e5ae86b6b6b17e/8) of an NFT I've gotten to display on Opensea from straight SVG data, using `image_data`.  Check out the encoding contract [here](https://optimistic.etherscan.io/address/0x5414b82985e995d5eb8ec57e928c5d738ff9827b#code#F1#L92).  I used https://www.base64decode.org/ to ensure encoding worked as intended.